# HP Omen with keys P1 through P6. How to get keys connected to them?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, mouse

The keys are supposed to respond to mouse events. Under windows the keys report the same as the keys to their right (so P1 -> ESC ... P6 -> Control)

These commands report nothing (used after a `sudo -i`:

```
cat /dev/input/mice | od -t x1 -w3 
xinput test-xi2 --root 
showkey --keycodes
acpi-listen
```

I also tried with `mev` (mouse version of xev) from `gpm`.

Is there a way to get these keys to react to a control-shift-something so I can attach an event?

This system also has a "omen key" (in between the delete and printscreen).

```
showkey --keycodes
```

shows

```
ACPI Error: Field [D128] at bit offset/length 128/1024 exceeds size of target Buffer (160 bits) (20181213/dsopcode-201)
kernel: [ 1677.596693] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [HWMC]
kernel: [ 1677.596694] Initialized Arguments for Method [HWMC]:  (2 arguments defined for method invocation)
kernel: [ 1677.596694]   Arg0:   0000000059a10415 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000002
kernel: [ 1677.596697]   Arg1:   0000000041b5acf7 <Obj>           Buffer(20) 53 45 43 55 01 00 00 00
kernel: [ 1677.596700] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \HWMC, AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT (20181213/psparse-531)
kernel: [ 1677.597104] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.WMID.WMAA, AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT (20181213/psparse-531)
```

and `acpi_listen` shows

```
95F24279-4D7B-43� 00000080 00000000
```

Comment: Fedora bug; https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1520703

Comment: In my case, ACPI_listen detects the "Omen" button but "P" keys are not detected at all